# What is the correct way to set bit in bitmask?

Tags: javascript, bit, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I'm little bit confuced about a proper way to set bits in bitmask. I have the following function and flags:

```
var userBmask = 0;

const EMAIL_CONFIRMED = 1;
const EMAIL_UNSUBSCRIBED = 2; 

setBit: function (bit) {
    userBmask |= 1 << bit; // 10
}
```

Let's say I want to set bit for email confirmation:

```
setBit(EMAIL_CONFIRMED);
```

After the line above my `userBmask` is: `10`. But I'm not sure this is correct because actualy I set second bit instead first. Should I rewrite `setBit` function to the folowing to set bits from most right bit?:

```
setBit: function (bit) {
    userBmask |= 1 << bit - 1; // 01
}
```

Now after `setBit(EMAIL_CONFIRMED)` I get result `01`

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your answers. Please look at the following. Becase I'm using javascript that is 32bit I can have bitmask with `0...31 bits. But if I try to set the last available bit (with is 31) I get negative number:

```
const NEXT_BIT = 31; 

setBit(NEXT_BIT); // userBmask now is -10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Is it expected behavior and could be result of possible bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are assuming that the lowest value bit is "bit one", this is actually not correct.

Consider "powers of two" which is the basis of binary numbers...

```
2^0 == 1 //first bit is "bit zero" 
2^1 == 2 //second bit is "bit one"
2^2 == 4 //third bit is "bit two"
2^3 == 8 //fourth bit is "bit three"
//and so on
```

If you shift 1 left by 1 then you go from 2^0 to 2^1.  So binary 10 is decimal 2.

If you want to set the lowest bit in userBmask when you pass 1 to your function then yes you'll have to subtract 1 from bit before you do the shift.

Answer (score 2):

set your constants to powers of two and use `or` without bitshift.

```
const EMAIL_CONFIRMED = 1<<0; //1
const EMAIL_UNSUBSCRIBED = 1<<1; //2
const NEXT_BIT1 = 1<<2; //4
const NEXT_BIT2 = 1<<3; //8

setBit: function (bit) {
    userBmask |= bit;
}

unsetBit: function (bit) {
    userBmask &= ~bit; //bitwise inverse
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer